# How to use a matcher to know if there is a non wanted character?

Tags: java, regex

I have this issue.

I was reading how to create the filters to later use them in a `pattern.match` in java in this way

```
public Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\\d{5,9}|\\d{9}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

My issue is this...

I want to string to start with a character (that is `[A-Z])` and later receive some numeric and alpha numeric characters (including some 
special characters like &. ' and so on)

The problem is that instead of allow the & and ' and all others, I want to deny some (allowing anything else).

So, I want to deny for example `%` and `*` and dont care if I get `&` or `'` inside the string.

I want to accept an alpha character at first and  deny `%, ', * , =` in all the string.

Is there any way to do it in the pattern.match?

Example

```
Asdafsd&2 = true
asdwwe%as = false
```

The problem is that I only know the few characters I want to deny... I mean, I must have 0 coincidences. And the string should have less than 15 characters...

Comment: It sounds unclear, but try `Pattern.compile("[A-Z][^%*]*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` if you need to match a string that starts with an ASCII letter and then has zero or more chars other than `%` and `*`.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what your regex should match? Some sample input strings that match and don't match would be helpful. *"and so on"* is particularly unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Ive updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to string to start with a character (that is [A-Z]) and later receive some numeric and alpha numeric characters (including some special characters like &. ' and so on)

So, if you were going to choose this path, you would be using something like

```
public Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][\\p{Alnum}&']*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

where `[A-Z]` matches an ASCII letter and `[\\p{Alnum}&']*` would match 0+ alphanumeric chars, or `&`, or `'`. And you would have to add more special chars that you'd allow. The list could grow really big if you wanted to allow almost all of those special chars.

> My issue is that instead of allow the & and ' and all others, I want to deny some (allowing anything else).

Then, you can rely on *negated character class*:

```
Pattern.compile("[A-Z][^%*]*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                      ^^^^^^
```

if you need to match a string that starts with an ASCII letter (`[A-Z]`) and then has zero or more chars other than `%` and `*` (`[^%*]*`).

See more about [**Negated Character Classes** here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

See this [Java demo](http://ideone.com/ZNWYnJ):

```
String pat = "(?i)[A-Z][^%'*=]{0,13}";
System.out.println("Asdafsd&".matches(pat)); // = true
System.out.println("asdwwe%as".matches(pat)); // = false
```

Here,

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `[A-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[^%'*=]{0,13}`  - 0 to 13 occurrences of a character other than `%`, `'`, `*` and `=`.

Since `String#matches` requires a full string match the `^`/`\A` and `$`/`\z` anchors are not necessary.

Comment: To clarify in case it is not clear from the snippet: it is the caret (^) symbol that negates the class.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, actually I want to have zero values of %, ', * , = , is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by zero values? Match any char except `%`, `'`, `*` , `=`? Use `[^%'*=]`. Mind the quantifiers: `*` matches zero or more occurrences, `+` matches 1 or more.

Comment: I want that if there is any %, ', * , = returns false, when the matcher matches zero or more occurrences is true, isnt it?

Comment: But you said you need the first char to be a *letter*. If you match the first letter, then the rest can be empty. As I said, if you need to match at least 1 char, use `+` quantifier.

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated my question, could you please take a look? Maybe I was not so clear at first...

Comment: Yes, and [here is another Java demo](http://ideone.com/3funFx). I do not think your question is clear, you should specify requirements in a clearer way: first char can be `[A-Za-z]`, then there must be zero or more characters other than `.....`. Something like this. Words like "deny", "don't care" do not sound like specifications. *And the string should have less than 15 characters*? Use `{0,14}` to match between 0 to 14 chars. If the first is a letter, then `{0,13}`.